# How to get result using between clause in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am new to sql, and i need to get data from DB table using between query.I tried but wont get required result. below is my table structure

EDIT :
I am trying to get interest rate as per the period specified in the query.
If i specify the period as 6 interest rate should be 3 and if even if a specify 11 rate should be 3 only.

suppose if period is 13 then rate should be 4.

```
    interest table
----------------------------------
id | year | min | max | interest |
----------------------------------
1  | 2019 | 6   | 11  |    3     |
1  | 2019 | 12  | 0   |    4     |
```

Below query returns me correct interest rate.

```
SELECT * FROM interest WHERE 6 BETWEEN min AND max AND year=2019
```

But when i pass value 5 it returns null but still i require result is ***"interest rate = 3"***.

and also when i pass 13 i should get result as ***"interest rate = 4"***
but i returns null.

I tried *** <= and >=*** even that's not working.
where am I going wrong..

Comment: your logic is not clear

Comment: Why would 5 return 3 when 5 is not between 6 and 11?

Comment: @Indrajeet evn the updated question fails to explain the logic behind your requirements. It is only clear that between is not enough for you, you need additional criteria as well.

Comment: @Indrajeet does max=0 mean that there is no upper bound to the periods? If so, consider changing that 9999999 (or sg similarly high value) and the between logic will work for that.

Comment: `But when i pass value 5 it returns null but still i require result is "interest rate = 3".` 5 is lower than your lowest min (6), therefore you really need to explain why the query should return 3 there instead of empty resultset. If you do not have a product for a certain period, then the answer should be no product is available. If somebody just forgot to enter the interest rate for periods 1-5, then you should not really make a guess. Alternatively, store 0 as a min, not 6.

Answer (score 0):

I you aren't in a position to 'fix' your interest table then you could adjust it by working out the min min value resetting this to 0 and similarly for the max min value

so given your data

```
    select i.*,
        case when min = (select min(min) from interest) then 0 else min end as minmin,
        case when min = (select max(min) from interest) then 999 else max end as maxmax
from interest i

returns
+------+------+------+------+----------+--------+--------+
| id   | year | min  | max  | interest | minmin | maxmax |
+------+------+------+------+----------+--------+--------+
|    1 | 2019 |    6 |   11 |        3 |      0 |     11 |
|    1 | 2019 |   12 |    0 |        4 |     12 |    999 |
+------+------+------+------+----------+--------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which can then be used to check your input value

```
    select s.*
from
(
select i.*,
        case when min = (select min(min) from interest) then 0 else min end as minmin,
        case when min = (select max(min) from interest) then 999 else max end as maxmax
from interest i
) s
where 5 between minmin and maxmax and year = 2019;

+------+------+------+------+----------+--------+--------+
| id   | year | min  | max  | interest | minmin | maxmax |
+------+------+------+------+----------+--------+--------+
|    1 | 2019 |    6 |   11 |        3 |      0 |     11 |
+------+------+------+------+----------+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```